# IME - How to handle key press

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode

In my game code, I process key input by handling `WM_KEYDOWN` message.
wParam gives me the keycode i need.

The problem is with IME, especially KoreanIME.
I get `WM_IME_COMPOSITION` and then `WM_KEYUP`, but never the `WM_KEYDOWN`.

So, the bottom line is.. I need to get keycode when i receive `WM_IME_COMPOSITION`.
Is there a way to do so?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374133(VS.85).aspx the composite key is in the wParam, encoded as DBCS (http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/cs.htm). I guess you have to extract the appropriate byte from the word and decide according to that.

Comment: thanks! i think this is it!! i will try this out when i get back to work

Comment: I could extract an ascii code from DBCS if IME is not in the middle of composition. While in composition, no, i couldn't

Comment: In the end, i used ImmSimulateHotKey() to turn ime off when not needed, and turn it back on later.

Comment: I couldn't use ImmAssociateContext( hwnd, NULL ) because under some configuration, right after I call it, it will be reassociated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but for the benefit of others, one could use

```
BOOL ImmDisableIME(
  __in  DWORD idThread
);
```

Pass the ID of the UI thread, the one which handles key presses.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318535(v=VS.85).aspx